# Woocomerce custom billing address fields display in order details

Tags: customization, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce I register a custom billing field to can track the house number separately

```
function addCheckoutHouseNrField($fields)
{
    $fields['billing_house_nr'] = array(
        'label' => __('Hausnummer'),
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'priority' => 35,
        'required' => true,
    );

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'addCheckoutHouseNrField');
```

which works fine. But how do I display this field after address_1 in emails and backend order details